# Player*First*JoinEvent how should i do that?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

so i tried to make a simple PlayerJoinEvent (*AKA. Player**First**JoinEvent*) for my server. Is there a way to do that? I want to run my code when player joins the server **first** time. I have tried multiple options like using `if(player.hasPlayedBefore())` but it doesent want to work! So, do you have an idea how to fix it or do it with a different method? Thanks to everyone for help!

Comment: In your player's long term data storage, have a DateTime column called "Last Log In" or some such which only gets populated when a player logs in and compare it against the current log in. Then compare those values to apply your First Log In event as needed. Be sure to compare _before_ updating the storage.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't probably deleted player data! If new player joins, new player data are created, only then does Spigot know, that the player is new to the server!

To do so:

- Shutdown your server
- Go to `server-folder/world/playerdata/*player-uuid*.dat`
- Delete *player-uuid*.dat
- Start the server

*Warning: This deletes player inventory!*

If your server is in offline mode, and you don`t know what your UUID is, use this [online tool](https://www.fabianwennink.nl/projects/OfflineUUID/).
If your server is in online mode, and you don't know your UUID, use [namemc](https://namemc.com/)

Code to test the event:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    if(!event.getPlayer().hasPlayedBefore()) {
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Hi!");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register this event in your main class!

Answer (score 0):

So i solved it and Thanks to everyone for help there wasnt any problem with hasPlayedBefore().